# SSL: DECRYPTION_FAILED_OR_BAD_RECORD_MAC in NPM and Python

Tags: python, npm, ssl-certificate, kaggle

Whenever I download any decent sized package in npm or python, I receive following error
[SSL: DECRYPTION_FAILED_OR_BAD_RECORD_MAC] decryption failed or bad record mac

Here is complete stack trace of error,

```
(Roaya_Test) E:\AI\Roaya\AI_Test_Scripts\Data>kaggle datasets download -d minhajuddinmeraj/anomalydetectiondatasetucf
Downloading anomalydetectiondatasetucf.zip to E:\AI\Roaya\AI_Test_Scripts\Data
... resuming from 20971520 bytes (41001681567 bytes left) ...
  0%|
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 198, in _run_module_as_main
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 88, in _run_code
  File "E:\AI\Roaya\AI_Test_Scripts\Roaya_Test\Scripts\kaggle.exe\__main__.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "E:\AI\Roaya\AI_Test_Scripts\Roaya_Test\Lib\site-packages\kaggle\cli.py", line 70, in main
    out = args.func(**command_args)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "E:\AI\Roaya\AI_Test_Scripts\Roaya_Test\Lib\site-packages\kaggle\api\kaggle_api_extended.py", line 1493, in dataset_download_cli
    self.dataset_download_files(dataset,
  File "E:\AI\Roaya\AI_Test_Scripts\Roaya_Test\Lib\site-packages\kaggle\api\kaggle_api_extended.py", line 1447, in dataset_download_files
    self.download_file(response, outfile, quiet, not force)
  File "E:\AI\Roaya\AI_Test_Scripts\Roaya_Test\Lib\site-packages\kaggle\api\kaggle_api_extended.py", line 1874, in download_file
    data = response.read(chunk_size)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "E:\AI\Roaya\AI_Test_Scripts\Roaya_Test\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\response.py", line 879, in read
    data = self._raw_read(amt)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "E:\AI\Roaya\AI_Test_Scripts\Roaya_Test\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\response.py", line 813, in _raw_read
    with self._error_catcher():
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\contextlib.py", line 155, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(typ, value, traceback)
  File "E:\AI\Roaya\AI_Test_Scripts\Roaya_Test\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\response.py", line 721, in _error_catcher
    raise SSLError(e) from e
urllib3.exceptions.SSLError: [SSL: DECRYPTION_FAILED_OR_BAD_RECORD_MAC] decryption failed or bad record mac (_ssl.c:2576)
```

This doesn't always happen but mostly do, for example last time I installed tensorflow this error continued to occur for 2 days before suddenly it worked. This inconsistency is puzzling me and happening in npm as well.

Right now im trying to run following command from kaggle

`kaggle datasets download -d minhajuddinmeraj/anomalydetectiondatasetucf Downloading anomalydetectiondatasetucf.zip to E:\AI\Roaya\AI_Test_Scripts\Data`

I tried to find anything to disable SSL certification on search but couldn't find anything relevant to this command since im not using anaconda

Comment: Disabling certificate checking wouldn't have helped, btw -- this is a data transfer problem, not a validation problem.

Answer (score 0):

This issue was resolved by moving from wifi to lan internet, for some reason this is causing issue for my pc. which is odd because on my laptop connected to same wifi this is working perfectly fine. So underlying issue is still not known.

Comment: Honestly, what's surprising me is that you weren't having bigger / more obvious problems with your wifi -- usually data corruption will fail the CRC and get content thrown out at a lower layer well before you even get to stronger checks later, but in this case it's one of those stronger checks that failed. CRCs aren't all that strong -- they _do_ miss things occasionally -- but if you have enough corruption going on for a CRC to miss some of it, that means that packets were getting thrown out for missing the CRCs _all the time_.